# phpBB / website integration - redirect works, but not if user puts in the wrong password

Tags: php, redirect, phpbb, phpbb3

I've got a website ([www.the289register.com/index-andy.html](http://www.the289register.com/index-andy.html)) and a phpBB3 forum ([www.the289register.com/phpBB3/](http://www.the289register.com/phpBB3)) and I've managed to integrate the two using a login form on the front page.  When a user logs in on the front page, they are redirected back using a hidden field in the form.  This all works fine.

However, if the user gets their password wrong, enters an incorrect username or leaves either field blank, the redirect does not work.

Since the site uses frames, this means the forum's ucp.php page then appears in a narrow bar on the left-hand-side where menu.php used to be.  This is obviously confusing to non-technical users.  I need to find a way to make the redirect work in all cases, ideally without modifying phpBB3 code so that my customisation does not get stomped on by any forum software upgrades in future.

I'm new to this, so apologies for any newbieness.  Here's what I have done in the side bar menu.php (stripped some stuff out to keep it brief):

```
<?php include_once("phpbb-integrate.php"); ?>

<?php
$cp = request_var('cp', '');
if ($cp == "logout") {
$user->session_kill();
$user->session_begin();
echo "Logged out";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<!--  ===== LOGIN BOX - DISPLAYS IF NOT SIGNED IN ====== -->

<?php
if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS) {
?>
<form method="POST" action="phpBB3/ucp.php?mode=login">
Forum Username:<br><input type="text" name="username" size="20"><br>
Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" size="20"><br>
Remember Me?: <input type="checkbox" name="autologin"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../menu.php">
</form>


<!--  ===== WELCOME THE USER IF SIGNED IN AND IS A CLUB MEMBER ====== -->
<?php
} elseif (in_array($user->data['group_id'], array(5,8,9))) {
?>
Welcome back, <?php echo $user->data['username_clean']; ?><br>You have <?php echo $user->data['user_unread_privmsg']; ?> new forum messages<br>

<form method="POST" action="menu.php?cp=logout">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../menu.php">
</form>


<!--  ===== WELCOME THE USER IF NON-MEMBER ====== -->
<?php
} else {
?>
Hello <?php echo $user->data['username_clean']; ?>. You're not yet a T289R member
<?php } ?>


<!--  ===== PUBLIC MENU ITEMS GO BELOW ====== -->
<?php
if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS) {
?>
<!--  ===== PRESENT A 'JOIN' LINK IF NON-MEMBER OR NOT SIGNED IN ====== -->
<li><a href="the289register/membershipnew.html" target="default">Join T289R!</a>
<?php } ?>

<!--  ===== PRESENT REMAINING PUBLIC LINKS ====== -->
<a href="http://wiki.the289register.com" target="_blank">289 Register Wiki</a>
<a href="phpBB3/index.php" target="_blank">Forum</a>


<?php
// MEMBER MENU LIST
if (in_array($user->data['group_id'], array(5,8,9))) {
?>

<!--  ===== MEMBERS MENU ITEMS GO BELOW ====== -->
<h3>Members Menu</h3>
<!-- <div id="side-bar"> -->
<a href="http://www.the289register.com/" target="_blank">Test link for member</a>

<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the content of phpbb-integrate.php:

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './phpBB3/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
?>
```

Like I say, redirection works fine if the username and password are put in correctly.  If the user messes anything up, the forum login page appears in the sidebar.

Any well-explained advice appreciated - I'm not much good with PHP yet.

Comment: The best way could be editing the file *includes/functions.php* because the field ["redirect"](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Practical.External_login) only works when the login is successful. Check the mod [**Prime Login Return**](https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/mod/prime_login_return), it's a little change in the code. Don't forget it when you want to update the phpbb's core.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Any pointers as to what to change in functions.php?   Unfortunately Prime Login Return is only for phpBB3 3.0.  We are using 3.1.6 and the developer of that extension has not modified it for this yet.

Comment: Looking at functions.php, I think this bit does the redirect if there is successful auth:  `if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
  {
   $redirect = request_var('redirect', "{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx");`

Comment: But in the section `if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_BREAK)` there is nothing about redirects.  Is this the part I need to modify, do you think?

Comment: I made the changes but i don't know if works. Be careful and try it in a test environment, never in production without to be sure. Remember to make a backup the file: http://pastebin.com/3vgukgsa

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately it didn't work.  It had no negative effect on the forum itself, but the redirect didn't happen.   I can send you the functions.php if you want?   The line numbers of the second modification (5249) didn't quite match because of another modification I have made previously.

Comment: I realised that two things need to happen actually.  If the user messes up their login, they need to be redirected back to the home page, but the also need to have some kind of message saying that they failed to log in.

Comment: It's a specific feature, try to contact with the author of mod, he has more experience with this than me: https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/author/primehalo

Comment: Ok - thanks for your help so far!  :)

Comment: You'll absolutely need to modify includes/functions.php. Two simple modifications and they do not corrupt anything other mods would rely on.

Comment: What version of phpBB are you running?

Comment: Hi Brian - it's 3.1.6

Comment: Modifying functions.php isn't a problem. The issue are the frames. The login will work, but each frame on load will need to run the auth checks as well. In your situation that's 5 auth checks. There's also the possibility of multiple sessions and cookies. I can help you make the changes needed, but you need to be sure you want to go down this road.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP's ucp.php file to handle the login (`<form method="POST" action="phpBB3/ucp.php?mode=login">`), but for what you want to do I would suggest using your own file to handle the login. That way you can choose exactly what happens when login fails.

The relevant part of the ucp.php file for logging in is this:

```
case 'login':
    if ($user->data['is_registered'])
    {
        redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx"));
    }

    login_box(request_var('redirect', "index.$phpEx"));
break;
```

And the relevant part of that code is the `login_box()` function from the functions.php file.

So lets say your sidebar menu file is menu.php. I'd copy phpBB's entire `login_box()` function from functions.php and paste it in menu.php, renaming it to something like `my_login_box`. Then, still in menu.php, you change your form action to point to menu.php. Next, add code to check to see if you have any incoming login info like a username or password (for example, `$POST['username']`) and if you do then execute my_login_box(). Finally, you'll need to modify the contents of my_login_box to do whatever it is you want it to do when a login fails or succeeds.

In this case, you shouldn't have to even worry about redirects. If the login succeeds, then have it print out a welcome message or something and don't print out the login form. If it fails, print out the error message and continue to display the form.